# HTML with Javascript animated background how to get divs on it?

Tags: javascript, css, html

my problem is I have a Javascript animated background ( just 3 pictures )
And I want to show some Div's on it with content on it.

I got this code atm:
In my css I got the stuff for the divs content but it won't show on the javascript it self

```
<head>

    <title></title>
    <link href="rekensite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

            <div class="hoi">
            <img id="change-me" src='w1.jpg' style="width:99%;height:99%" alt='[]' />
            <div class="main">
            <div class="Back">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="content">


        <script>

        var
            images = [ "11.jpg", "22.jpg", "33.jpg" ] //the list of images
          , imgToCHange = document.getElementById( 'change-me' )
          , interval = 1000 //in ms
          ;

        setInterval( function(){
          images.unshift( images.pop() );
          imgToCHange.src = images[0];
         }, interval );

        </script>


        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div></div>
<div class="Bottom"><br/> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (if I understand your question correctly) that you are trying to put divs over an image. You need to set the background image of a div ("hoi" in your case I think) and then that div can contain all the other divs. In the demo I've simply removed your image and set the image style on the "hoi" div (and added a blue border so you can see it) and then I've updated the JavaScript so that it updates the background image. This should work fine with your images.

See my jsbin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/eHUJOpo/2/edit?html,js,output).

HTML

```
<div class="hoi" id="change-me" style="width:99%;height:99%;border:1px solid blue">
            This is where the image was
            <div class="main">main
            <div class="Back">back
    <div class="header">Header
    <div class="menu">menu
    <div class="content">content
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var
    images = [ "11.jpg", "22.jpg", "33.jpg" ] //the list of images
  , imgToCHange = document.getElementById( 'change-me' )
  , interval = 1000 //in ms
  ;

setInterval( function(){
  images.unshift( images.pop() );
  imgToCHange.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[0] + ")";
 }, interval );
```